# How can I load a TreePanel with local JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, treepanel

How can I load some arbitrary data into treepanel using local JSON object? All of the examples shipped with ExtJS 4.0 distribution work with AJAX requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example using a [MemoryProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory.html) in the Sencha Documentation.  Use that as your proxy instead of an ajax proxy.